# How to get id by selected item in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a canvas and I add a rectangle in it. Each rectangle has its own ID. How can I get the ID by double clicking on the rectangle on the canvas? It can be either Alert or consolLog.
Example: http://fabricjs.com/manage-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own properties to an object. For example<sup>[1]</sup>:

```js
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  // ...
  metaData: {
    id: 'myId'
  }
});
```

Then you can get if on select for example:

```js
rect.on('selected', e => {
  console.log(canvas.getActiveObject().metaData?.id);
});
```

Live example:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// create a rectangle object
const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  metaData: {
    id: 'myId'
  }
});

// add "selected" listener
rect.on('selected', e => {
  console.log(canvas.getActiveObject().metaData?.id);
});

// "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.2.0/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-Pdu3zoEng2TLwwjnDne3O7zaeWZfEJHU5B63T+zLtME/wg1zfeSH/1wrtOzOC37u2Y1Ki8pTCdKsnbueOlFlMg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Of course you can also add it as a direct property (without the `metaData`) but maybe it will be better to remind you that it's not fabris property but yours

Comment: Can't I write without it in metadata? Why are we writing in metadata?

Comment: It is possible. Just for you (or your colleagues) to remember that it's a prop you added.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!